# Contractible space of maps between Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, mapping-space

Suppose $A$ is an abelian torsion group, with no elements of order $p$, and let 
$P$ be an abelian $p$-group (i.e., the order of each element is a power of $p$).
It sure seems to me that 
$$
\mathrm{map}_*( K(A,n), K(P,m) ) \sim *
$$
for all $n, m\geq 1$.

Unfortunately, I want to prove this without homology or (explicitly) cohomology.

If $A$ is finite, then we can boil the question down to the case of a cyclic group
$\mathbb{Z}/a$ with $(a,p) = 1$; 
then there is a cofiber sequence $M\to B\mathbb{Z}/a \to X$
where $M = S^1 \cup_a D^2$ is the "$1$-dimensional Moore space" for $\mathbb{Z}/a$
and 
$X$ has a cone decomposition using Moore spaces $M(\mathbb{Z}/a,k)$ for $k\geq 2$.

Since (as is easily shown)  $\mathrm{map}_{*}( M(\mathbb{Z}/a,n), K(P,m) ) \sim \star$, 
we get 
$
\mathrm{map}_{*}( B\mathbb{Z}/a, K(P,m)) \sim *$,
and then homotopy  colimit stuff proves the assertion for finite $A$.

Question:  Is there such an "elementary" argument for the general case?

Comment: Just come across this. "Unfortunately, I want to prove this without homology or (explicitly) cohomology." Why? 

I ask this as my 1962 PhD had to do with mapping spaces and Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces. But I did use cohomology, chain complexes, Dold-Kan, ...

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't one filter $A$ by finite subgroups $A_j$ and use
$$
\text{map}_*(K(A,n),K(P,m)) = \lim_j \quad \text{map}_*(K(A_j,n),K(P,m)) ,
$$
the fact that the limit and homotopy limit coincide in this case, and finally that you are taking the homotopy limit of contractible spaces over a diagram which has contractible shape?

Comment: Doesn't this just get the result for locally finite groups $A$?

Comment: Or is this not a problem because I'm working only with abelian groups?


Comment: This gives it for countably generated ones. But a similar argument works I think by filtering $A$ by its poset $\cal P_A$ of finite subgroups and inclusions, and then noting that $\cal P_A$ is contractible (since if $B_\alpha \subset A$ is a finite diagram of finite subgroups, then the subgroup generated by all of these is still finite; this shows that $\cal P_A$ is contractible.